Do a distinct in SQL, ordered by another column
Say I have a table like this:



column 1
timestamp




a
1


a
2


a
3


b
4


b
5


a
6


a
7



I need the output of the query like this:



column 1
timestamp




a
1


b
4


a
6



i.e., I just need to track the changes in columns, and the min timestamp against it, but I'm not able to think of a way to do this. Suggest me the optimal query which can help me do this. Please try to keep the CTEs/Subqueries to the minimum, as the data is huge. Thanks. The SQL I'm using is PrestoSQL.

Gaps and islands.

It's a gap & island problem.here is how you can do it:
with cte as 
(
select * 
  , row_number() over (order by timestamp) - 
    row_number() over (partition by column1 order by  timestamp) as grp
from my_table
  )

select column1, min(timestamp) as timestamp
from cte 
group by column1, grp
order by timestamp

output:



column1
timestamp




a
1


b
4


a
6



fiddle

Use lag() window function to get the previous row's column1 value. Return rows where column1 is not the same as previous column1 value.
with cte as 
(
    select * 
      , lag(column1) over (order by timestamp) as lagcolumn1
    from my_table
)

select column1, timestamp
from cte 
where column1 is distinct from lagcolumn1
order by timestamp

Demo: https://dbfiddle.uk/LiWi0DRR (Based on @eshirvana's fiddle, thank you!)

Not sure that Presto/Trino supports the is distinct from syntax, I would go with the original where column1 <> lagcolumn1 or lagcolumn1 is null approach

@GuruStron, seems to be supported, https://teradata.github.io/presto/docs/141t/functions/comparison.html.

Yes, found it in Trino docs too.

@madhan01, this answers your question. If you have a multiple column issue, you should have given us that information before we spent time helping you.
